# How do i get charge info from customer object in stripe

Tags: php, api, stripe-payments

After successful payment . i print_r($customer) to get card and charge information .I received this ,i only able to get first `Stripe_Customer Object` information but not `Stripe_Card Object` from `$customer` variable

```
Stripe_Card Object ([_apiKey:protected] => sk_test_... [_values:protected] 
=> Array ( [id] => card_1BLsOAJ6IzxnlSnmpPloNXUN 
[object] => card [address_city] => lahore 
[address_country] => Pakistan
```

only first `Stripe_Customer Object` of array can easily get e.g

```
echo  $customer['id']
```

i try many times to get information of card object using these methods but not work for me

```
echo $customer->source->card->address_country;
echo $customer->source->address_country;
echo $customer['card'];
echo $customer['address_country'];
echo $customer['card']['address_country'];
```

Comment: Give full response here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A customer can have more than one source at the same time. The `source` property on the Customer is a list as documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api#customer_object-sources). If you want to access the card object you'd need to do something like this:

```
$card = $customer->sources->data[0];
$cardId = $card->id;
$cardLast4 = $card->last4;
// etc.
```

Comment: [koopajah](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1606729/koopajah)  Why Card object `data[0]` on 0 position if card object array positioned on 4th after print_r($customer). why not on `sources->data[4]` ?

Comment: Because you explicitly mentioned getting a customer object back which means you either created it right now and it's the first card or you updated the customer's `source` in which case it should also be the first. It was just an example ultimately, if you use https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_card you would get a Card object back